# Core Data + NSTextView + Undo Manager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, swift

I'm trying to make non-trivial job for Core Data backed with NSTextView. I want to store in my Core Data model not the whole NSTextStorage, but instead to break it into paragraphs and to persist those paragraphs each in individual entity.

In fact I got that all to work. But I can't deal with undo/redo support. If I store every change in TextDidChange notification or something, I basically lose NSTextView's undo support, because Core Data begins to store every single character which did entered the text storage. So, the undo manager registers that actions individually. And when I undo, I get undo just character-by-character and that isn't the thing I want. If I don't store inputted text in Core Data, textview's undo management works fine.

How can I know when the undo manager begins and closes a group of actions, so I could store changes only when a group will be closed?

I was trying to observe NSUndoManagerDidCloseUndoGroupNotification of NSUndoManager but it didn't help, because I get that notification during every single character input and still get that annoying character-by-character undo behavior.

Is it even possible to get the workaround?

UPDATE: I was able to achieve my goal by disableUndoRegistration() while I'm updating a Core Data entity. But I'm wondering if there's another solution.

Comment: would appreciate at least a reason, why did I get -1. I think it's interesting task to explore core data deeply, because the default implementation of backing it with NSTextView is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I did it. Eventually, that wasn't too hard. But it really took some time.
Here's my repository for NSTextStorage that tracks paragraphs: https://github.com/CineDev/ParagraphTextKit